# Why does VS crash as i try open a C# class in the editor (abstract inheritance issue?)

Tags: c#

I am reciving a strange error and it is causing VS to crash, to what i have managed to gather it is due to the fact that VS tries to instanciate the class (wich is inheriting an interface & abstract class)i am about to open as to run the code in the backround and try my code i add or any changes.

The icon is not as the regular class icon's in the solution explorer but it looks like the Form icon instead, As soon as i remove the inheritance it goes into a regular class icon and i can dubble klick it and VS does not crash but instead opens the class in the editor.

the classes:

```
namespace Tester
{
   interface ITest
   {

      string ID { get; set; }

      double age { get; set; }        


   }
}
```

The next one:

```
namespace Tester
{
public abstract class Trial : ITest
{
    //Declaring variables
    string m_ID;
    double m_age;

    string ID 
    { 
        get { return m_ID; }
        set { m_ID = value; }
    }

    double age 
    {
        get { return m_age; }
        set { m_age = value; }
    }

}
}
```

Next one is:

```
 namespace Tester
{
public class Time : Trial
{
    //Declaring variables
    private bool m_isfast;


    /// <summary>
    /// Default constructor
    /// </summary>
    public Time()
    {
    }

    public bool IsFast
    {
        get { return m_isfast; }
        set { m_isfast = value; }
    }

}
}
```

Last one is:

```
  namespace Tester
  {
  class BanditOne : Time
  {
        //Declaring variables
        private bool m_isTransAm;

        /// <summary>
        /// Constructor
        /// </summary>
        public BanditOne()
        {
        }

        public bool IsTransAm
        {
            get { return m_isTransAm; }
            set { m_isTransAm = value; }
        }


        new public string GetRaceSpecificData()
        {                
            string strout = (string.IsNullOrEmpty(strInfo) ? string.Empty : strInfo);

            if (IsTransAm)
            {
                strout += string.Format("\nProduces #1");
            }
            if (IsFast)
            {
                strout += (IsFast ? "\nFast as lightning! " : "\nSlow like a snail.");
            }
          return strout;

        }
        }
```

I hope someone got an idea as i am all out :/ Is there something i have completely misunderstood or missed about abstract classes perhaps?

Comment: What happens if you make 'ITest' and 'BanditOne' public?

Comment: Same effect :/ I just cant figure it out.

Comment: Which method is `BanditOne.GetRaceSpecificData` hiding? You only need `new` if you're hiding a method in a base class with the same signature. Try removing `new`. Also, have you tried restarting VS?

Comment: Before the point it is going to crash, start another instance of VS and attach that debugger to the instance of your solution.  Then do the action in your solution to cause the crash and inspect any exceptions in the attached debugger.

Comment: VS chrashes as it is about to load the class into the editor so there is no place to put the debugger. :(

Comment: Start two blank instances of VS. In one instance, Debug -> Attach to Process, select the other instance of VS you started. Now switch to the other instance of VS that is attached, load your solution like you normally would.